# Algorithm for 3D mesh model segmentation to chart

Tags: texture, algorithm, computational-geometry, mesh, uv-mapping

I'm trying to implement a segmentation model which will divide a 3d mesh model into charts. But I'm having really hard time to find resources in the web. The papers and some other places these approaches discussed either in very brief or with very complicated math. Really need some step by step guide with example for the algorithm. I'm particularly interested on the approach given in this [LSCM](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Levy02.pdf) paper.

There is another algorithm discussed in [here](http://the-witness.net/news/2010/03/graphics-tech-texture-parameterization/) and the code for this can be found in this [repo](https://github.com/Thekla/thekla_atlas). This also looks very promising.